# Linear model with errors of x- and y-values

Tags: r, originlab

I have data that I have to fit with a linear model.
I also have errors associated with every one of the x and y values.

Basically I want to do something like this (all vectors of the same length):

```
lm(y_data +- y_errors ~ x_data +- x_errors)
```

But obviously that does not work.

It seems Origin can do it (http://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/LinearFit-XErr-Dialog).

How can I tell R to use the x- and y-errors for creating a linear model, like Origin does?

Comment: Are random variables, as in "errors-in-variables regression?"

Comment: Have you looked at the references in the Origin documentation? This should be relatively straight-forward to implement in R.

Comment: Why `+-` and not just `+`?

Comment: maybe http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/rgr/html/gx.rma.html ; try `library("sos")` and then use `findFn` for e.g. `"{reduced major axis}", `"errors in variables"`, or names of authors in Origin references ...

Comment: I have looked at the origin documentation more closely, and they state that they use 1 / sigma^2 (inverse variance?) as weight for their linear fitting algorithm. I know that I can specify weight in lm, but I have two vectors that I want to put in.

I think implementing a chi-squared optimisation myself would probably be the easiest solution right now ...

Answer (score 0):

Considering x and y can have errors of xe and ye, respectively. For every (x,y) combination if following combinations are added and analyzed, they may get you what you want. Try and compare with originlab results.

```
x,y
x-xe, y-ye
x+xe, y+ye
x-xe, y+ye
x+xe, y-y2
```

To get these combinations, try following code (replace x, y, xe and ye by your data)

```
x = c(1,2,3,4)
xe = 0.1
y = c(12, 24, 28, 46)
ye = 1.3

ddf = data.frame(xx=as.numeric(), yy=as.numeric())
i=1
counter=1
while(i<(length(x)+1)){
    ddf[counter,]=c(x[i],y[i])
    ddf[counter+1,]=c(x[i]-xe,y[i]-ye)
    ddf[counter+2,]=c(x[i]+xe,y[i]+ye)
    ddf[counter+3,]=c(x[i]-xe,y[i]+ye)
    ddf[counter+4,]=c(x[i]+xe,y[i]-ye)
    counter = counter+5
    i = i+1
}
ddf
    xx   yy
1  1.0 12.0
2  0.9 10.7
3  1.1 13.3
4  0.9 13.3
5  1.1 10.7
6  2.0 24.0
7  1.9 22.7
8  2.1 25.3
9  1.9 25.3
10 2.1 22.7
11 3.0 28.0
12 2.9 26.7
13 3.1 29.3
14 2.9 29.3
15 3.1 26.7
16 4.0 46.0
17 3.9 44.7
18 4.1 47.3
19 3.9 47.3
20 4.1 44.7
```

Then run the test:

```
with(ddf, lm(yy~xx))

Call:
lm(formula = yy ~ xx)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           xx  
      1.169       10.533
```

Comment: Looking at the linked documentation, I don't think this is what the OP actually wants to do.

Comment: It will be interesting to compare with originlab results. Maybe OP should check at CrossValidated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/